# Databricks, SPARK UI, sql logs: Retrieve with REST API

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-community-edition

Is it possible to retrieve Databricks/Spark UI/SQL logs using the rest-API, any retention limit?, can't see any related API [rest-api azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/)

> Note: cluster /advanced options/logging has not been set.

Answer (score 0):

`cluster_log_conf:`  The configuration for delivering Spark logs to a long-term storage destination. Only one destination can be specified for one cluster. If the conf is given, the logs will be delivered to the destination every
5 mins. The destination of driver logs is //driver, while the destination of executor logs is //executor.

Refer [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters#--request-structure)

Comment: thanks for your reply, however, the question is about possibility of databricks rest-api usage for this task.